# Convert IF statement To CASE

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I know bit of a primitive question, but I have drawn a mental block. I am looking to convert this `if else` into a `CASE` statement. How can I achieve this?

```
   If (strReplaceCharsInString.Contains("&")) Then
            strResult = strReplaceCharsInString.Replace("&", "&amp;")
        Else
            If (strReplaceCharsInString.Contains("'")) Then
                strResult = strReplaceCharsInString.Replace("'", "&apos;")
            Else
                If (strReplaceCharsInString.Contains(">")) Then
                    strResult = strReplaceCharsInString.Replace(">", "&gt;")
                Else
                    If (strReplaceCharsInString.Contains("<")) Then
                        strResult = strReplaceCharsInString.Replace("<", "&lt;")
                    Else
                        If (strReplaceCharsInString.Contains("""")) Then
                            strResult = strReplaceCharsInString.Replace("""", "&quote;")
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Can this be achieve by Regex to match the pattern and then do a select case?

Comment: What if your string contains both `&` _and_ `>`, only `&` will get encoded.  You don't really want to use flow control (`if`/`else`, `select case` etc) for this type of work.  Also, [methods exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for doing this work.

Comment: Yes I only realised that, after posting the question... hence I updated it to see if it could be done via Regex @JamesThorpe

Comment: Yes, it probably could.  But I wouldn't - I'd use the method I linked to above :)

Comment: Does this method encode ' apostrophe?@JamesThorpe

Comment: Not sure, but it's encoded everything it's ever needed to for me.  Apostrophe's don't generally need to be encoded in HTML, they're potentially more of an issue in javascript etc.

Comment: quickly found this, in this blog it mentions it does not encode '. Yeah i guess. I wonder if it would cause an issue, only way to find out is to test it Thanks :) http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx @JamesThorpe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an if nor do you need a case.
The first thing the Replace method does is check if the value exists in the string.
Therefor your code can be safely replaced by this code:

```
strResult = strReplaceCharsInString.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("'", "&apos;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace("""", "&quote;")
```

or if you want it in different lines you can of course do this:

```
strResult = strReplaceCharsInString.Replace("&", "&amp;")
strResult = strResult.Replace("'", "&apos;")
strResult = strResult.Replace(">", "&gt;")
strResult = strResult.Replace("<", "&lt;")
strResult = strResult.Replace("""", "&quote;")
```

of course, it will be better to use [HTMLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method provided by Microsoft for these specific replaces, as James Thorpe suggested in the comments.

You should consider the possibility that your input string is already HTML Encoded, meaning it contains things like `&amp;` and `&lt;`. This replace will then mess up your string as it will replace the `&` in every one of these substrings to `&amp;`, leaving you with a string containing things like `&amp;amp;` and `&amp;lt;`

This is yet another reason why you should use HTMLEncode rather then replacing everything yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how does this cope with string having ">" and "&"?

Comment: They are independent in this code, meaning they both would be replaced. However, you should consider the possibility that your input string is already HTML Encoded, meaning it contains things like &amp; and &lt;. This replace will then mess up your string as it will replace the & in every one of these substrings to &amp;, leaving you with a string containing thinks like &amp;amp; and &amp;lt;